# Determine vacation from start and end column for each day

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime, explode

I got the following df which is kind of an absence/vacation table of employees:

```
Index Name  Start      End
0     Eric  20.07.2022 20.07.2022
1     Ric   21.07.2022 17.08.2022
2     Seth  15.07.2022 21.07.2022 
3     Eric  16.07.2022 16.07.2022
...
```

The final df should look like this and should give information whether an employee is on vacation or not:

```
Name  15.07.2022 16.07.2022 17.07.2022 18.07.2022 19.07.2022 20.07.2022 21.07.2022 22.07.2022 ... 17.08.2022
Eric  No         Yes        No         No         No         Yes         No        No             No
Ric   No         No         No         No         No         No          Yes       Yes            Yes
Seth  Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes         Yes       No             No
```

Any suggestions how to do this? I tried it with `explode` and `groupby`, but failed so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# ensure datetime
df[['Start', 'End']] = df[['Start', 'End']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

out = (df
  # assign range of dates in the desired format
 .assign(date=[pd.date_range(s, e, freq='D').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
               for s,e in zip(df['Start'], df['End'])],
         value='Yes' # assign default "Yes"
        )
 .explode('date') # create rows
 .pivot_table(index='Name', columns='date', values='value',
              # get first "Yes", fill missing with "No"
              aggfunc='first', fill_value='No')
 # cosmetic changes
 .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   Name 01.08.2022 02.08.2022 03.08.2022 04.08.2022 05.08.2022 06.08.2022 07.08.2022 08.08.2022 09.08.2022 10.08.2022 11.08.2022 12.08.2022 13.08.2022 14.08.2022 15.07.2022 15.08.2022 16.07.2022 16.08.2022 17.07.2022 17.08.2022 18.07.2022 19.07.2022 20.07.2022 21.07.2022 22.07.2022 23.07.2022 24.07.2022 25.07.2022 26.07.2022 27.07.2022 28.07.2022 29.07.2022 30.07.2022 31.07.2022
0  Eric         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No        Yes         No         No         No         No         No        Yes         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No
1   Ric        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes         No        Yes         No        Yes         No        Yes         No         No         No        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes
2  Seth         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No        Yes         No        Yes         No        Yes         No        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No         No
```

Comment: Nice that worked! But how can i sort the columns by date? And how to add a new row with the sum of Yes for each column?

Comment: If you keep the columns as datetime they will be sorted automatically, you can convert to string later if needed. To add a total (which wasn't requested in your question), simply add a `.assign(total=lambda d: d.sum(axis=1))`